# Combining Chrome async APIs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, asynchronous

I need to combine two Chrome APIs in loop and after the loop is finished, save array to storage.
This is what I have

```
chrome.downloads.search({}, function (DownloadItem) {
    for (var i=0; i<DownloadItem.length; i++) {
        var itemID = DownloadItem[i].id;
        chrome.downloads.getFileIcon(itemID, function(iconURL) {
            DL_icons[itemID] = iconURL;
        });     
    }
    console.log(DL_icons);
});
```

result of `search` is `DownloadItem` array of objects. I need to loop through it, get ID's, and for every ID I need to pass it into call of `chrome.downloads.getFileIcon`.
Result of that `getFileIcon` method is `iconURL` which I need to push into new array on ID index (I could store it into new object with according ID and then push it into an array, doesn't matter in this case).

After everything is done, I need to store it to local storage (or console.log...).
As it is now, I'm getting the same ID and iconURL for every array element.
Basically, I need to make a proper closure of inner API, and just can't make it right. Can someone pls help with it?

Comment: Looks like a mix of the [everyday AJAX problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call), and the [infamous loop closure issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: should I split it into outer function? would that help?

Comment: btw. I can't use IIFE, because in that case, I can't get IDs.... or can I?

Comment: @elclanrs I stand corrected :) IIEF is solution, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone stumble on simmmilar problem, this is how I solve it, thanx to @elclanrs suggestion

it is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example/19324832#19324832)

```
chrome.downloads.search({}, function (DownloadItem) {
    for (var i=0; i<DownloadItem.length; i++) {
        var itemID = DownloadItem[i].id;
        (function(index) {
            chrome.downloads.getFileIcon(index, function(iconURL) {
                DL_icons[index] = iconURL;
                console.log(DL_icons);
            });
        })(itemID);         
    }
});
```

instead of passing the loop index, I passed my ID variable... job's done